# Acer E1-470 new partition created can't be use

Tags: partitioning, 13.10, acer, gparted

I can't use the new partition. I was using Gpar to shrink and make a new partition. Why I can't use the new partition. If I just open it will be just empty folder.

Answer (score 0):

You first make the partition with gparted (or any tool you like).

You next format the partition , again with gparted if you wish. Make it ext4 unless you know you need another format.

Last, you mount the partition. You do this temporarily with the command line or add an entry in fstab to mount at boot.

Example:

```
sudo mkdir /media/new_partition
sudo mount /dev/dsXY /media/new_partition
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab or update your question if you need further assistance.